# How can I install passenger-nginx from Ansible?

Tags: ruby, nginx, rubygems, passenger, ansible

I'm trying to run an installation of the passenger web server with nginx on Ubuntu 12.04, using Ansible 1.4.1     It seems that the gem install is messing up or something, because ansible doesn't find the command, and when I reinstall the gem by hand it works.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# ruby.yml

- name: "install ruby"
  script: scripts/install_ruby.sh

- name: "Install bundler"
  gem: name=bundler state=latest

- name: "Install passenger"
  gem: name=passenger state=latest

- name: "Copy nginx upstart"
  copy: src=nginx.conf dest=/etc/init/nginx.conf mode=0644 owner=root group=root

- name: Install passenger-nginx
  command: passenger-install-nginx-module --auto-download --auto --prefix=/opt/nginx --extra-configure-flags='--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module' creates=/opt/nginx

- name: "Enable Nginx"
  service: name=nginx state=started enabled=yes
```

Error:

```
TASK: [common | install ruby] *************************************************
changed: [staging-2.coinvalley.com]

TASK: [common | Install bundler] **********************************************
ok: [staging-2.coinvalley.com]

TASK: [common | Install passenger] ********************************************
ok: [staging-2.coinvalley.com]

TASK: [common | Copy nginx upstart] *******************************************
ok: [staging-2.coinvalley.com]

TASK: [common | Install passenger-nginx] **************************************
failed: [staging-2.coinvalley.com] => {"cmd": ["passenger-install-nginx-module", "--auto-download", "--auto", "--prefix=/opt/nginx", "--extra-configure-flags=--with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module"], "failed": true, "item": "", "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

When I ssh in, I see the gem present:

root@staging-2:~# gem list

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.3)
bundler (1.5.2)
daemon_controller (1.1.8)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
passenger (4.0.36)
psych (2.0.2)
rack (1.5.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
```

However, when I try to run the install command, it still isn't working:

```
root@staging-2:~# passenger-install-nginx-module
passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found
```

It only work if I rerun:

```
gem install passenger
```

Ruby was installed from source, and here's my gem env

```
root@staging-2:~# gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

I see the executables present in the GEM PATH directory:

```
- /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
```

but apparently this isn't being added to the main path?

Could Ansible's gem module be using the [--user-install option](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install) behind the scenes?

Ok, apparently it is:  http://docs.ansible.com/gem_module.html#gem-manage-ruby-gems

Leaving question for reference for anyone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu, just use Ansible to install [the Phusion Passenger Debian packages](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download#open_source) (click on "Ubuntu") through apt-get. It works exactly the same as apt-getting anything else, is much easier than installing using RubyGems, and even installs all necessary dependencies for you (including Ruby itself!)

Comment: Thanks for commenting!  I remember previously, it was advised to recompile nginx if we wanted to use passenger, or other nginx modules.  Would the package you referenced let me still use those and skip the compilation step?  (I'm using --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module).

Comment: Our Debian packages include almost every Nginx module that currently exist on earth. Check the package descriptions, e.g. using Aptitude, to see what modules are included.

Answer (score 2):

Breaks because Ansible now uses the user_install option for gem installs by default, as of Ansible 1.3

http://docs.ansible.com/gem_module.html#gem-manage-ruby-gems

[--user-install option](http://guides.rubygems.org/faqs/#user-install)